# Why does Wunderlist not load in private Firefox?

Tags: firefox, private-browsing, wunderlist

If I login to *Wunderlist* from a private tab in Firefox, it keeps reloading `https://www.wunderlist.com/webapp#` over and over. In Chrome, I have no such problem; I can access it from private tab.

Now the first step of the answer to the popular question ["why won't Wunderlist load in Firefox?"](https://support.wunderlist.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1649112) in Wunderlist's FAQ seems to impy it is by design.

> **1. Ensure that you are not using Wunderlist in Private Browsing mode**

My question is two-fold:

1. ***Why* was Wunderlist designed to not work in private browsing mode in Firefox?**
2. **Is there a known workaround for this, by tweaking the settings for instance?**
   (Other than using a different browser).

Comment: I've encountered many pages like this before (IIRC even Facebook and gmail didn't work in private mode on FF) and am too very interested in a possible reason or fix for this.

Comment: I don't know about FF but in Safari there was a bug which disabled local storage in private mode - maybe it's something similar?